# Django: Handling of duplicated values on unique rows

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a row of data and in it consist of Protein object. Protein Object has unique
protein_id (not PK) and rows of data can have repeatable protein object.

So when a user creates a row of data say Data: {'protein_id':ABC123} if the given protein_id already exists in database, we'll use that protein object.

I am able to create the protein object when it does not exist in database. But when it already exist, I am getting "protein with this protein id already exists.".

I understand that this happens because I am creating new protein object with the same protein_id and protein_id has a unique=True attribute.
But what I am not understanding is (Refer below for details) why I am unable to get the object if exist or why is the exception getting thrown (Not sure whats the logic behind).

##### Models.py

```
class Protein(models.Model):
    protein_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False,unique=True)
    sequence = models.CharField(max_length=40000,blank=True)
```

##### Serializer.py

```
class ProteinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Protein
        fields = ['protein_id',"sequence"]
    def create(self,validated_data):
        protein_data = validated_data.pop('protein')
        protein = None
        try:
            protein = Protein.objects.get(protein_id=protein_data['protein_id'])
        except Protein.DoesNotExist:
            protein = Protein.objects.create(**protein_data)
        return protein
```

What I have tried here is a try-except where the serializer will first get the protein object in database and if it can't be found it will throw an exception which will then create the protein object.
I have also tried get_or_create() and i think the logic is the same with these 2 methods.

So I am not sure why I am still creating the object (throwing an exception) when it can be found. Or am I having a wrong approach? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exception is thrown when the object does not exist (is not found), so the logic you've implemented seems correct. Although I don't understand your statement in the last paragraph _"So I am not sure why I am still creating the object (throwing an exception) when it can be found"_

Comment: `protein_data` does not have `protein_id` or it contains value of `id` - integer PK identity value, not your charfield value.

Comment: @donald What I meant to say is, getting "protein with this protein_id already exists." means im creating protein with a duplicate protein_id and the creation code is within the except clause. However why is the except clause being thrown when I can get the object? Maybe my try clause has some issue?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Regarding protein_data, I have confirmed that it contains 'protein_id' and can be retrieved by protein_data['protein_id'] and it does not contain id or pk as I think Django will auto assign an auto increment pk.

Comment: I also realised that if the object already exist, the application raised a BAD REQUEST error before even hitting the create method.